# How does Apple sign apps that it recompiles from bitcode?

Tags: app-store-connect, digital-signature, software-distribution, itunes-store

I create an app and I sign it and send it to Apple, along with bitcode.

Apple redistributes to millions of people and they can verify my code signature.

Now Apple recompiles my app and distributes again.

How are they able to sign the app so that it will run on those millions of people's devices? Do they have access to my private key and are they forging my signature?

Comment: I'm struggling to figure this out too. Have you found the answer to this question?

Answer (score 0):

The words of Felix Krause, the "Professional iOS Code Signing Issue Resolver" and the creator of `fastlane` tool:

> "You sign your app and Apple has to sign it also... The fact that you have to code sign on local machine is actual nonsense because Apple basically resigns your app anyway once it gets approved."

For us that means that Apple uses another key pair to sign the app even if they don't have to rebuild it from bitcode. So that's the answer - they don't have access to user's private key, they resign the App with their key. And in case of recompiling app from bitcode - even simpler: compile bitcode, sign binary with App Store key.